# Find data to perform regression analysis

Tags: analysis, regression, correlation, online-resources, data-analysis

I'm trying to find some data (two continuous variables that I believe are correlated) online for which I can perform a regression anaylsis, my assignment sheet says:

> The data may be found anywhere on the web or in books, journals or
>   magazines in the library1. You are free to do any type of analysis
>   (using data of types a., b., or c) that is of interest to you or
>   relevant to your course. The only limitations are that:
>
> 1. The data must be secondary (it cannot come from a survey that you conduct yourself);
> 2. The data must not have already been analysed within the source from which it is obtained;
> 3. The sample size must be at least 25 observations

Could anyone recommend any sources for which I could find some data.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ngrams from Google books](http://books.google.com/ngrams) (there is a lot of data to download, probably even too much). For example [Marie Skłodowska-Curie and Pierre Currie](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Marie+Curie%2C+Pierre+Curie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) are definetely correlated ;-)

**Edit:** [Color vs. colour](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=color%2C+colour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) will probably be enough for you (only one file to download).

Cheers!